# How to combine the value of a column with same key in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapstruct

Suppose I have this data

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| row1 | valueA |
| row1 | valueB |
| row2 | valueB |

How can I join the value of Column B that has the same value in Column A? Example:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| row1 | valueA, valueB |
| row2 | valueB |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collect_set` and `concat_ws`.

```
df.select("ColumnA","ColumnB")
  .groupBy("ColumnA")
  .agg(concat_ws(",",collect_set("ColumnB")))
```